# JPA Simple ForeignKey relationship

Tags: jpa

Is it possible to create a basic FK relationship in JPA without involving the full entity target object?

As an example, imagine I have an entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Mechanic")
public class Mechanic {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    //...
```

and a `Car` that I want to reference a `Mechanic.id`:

```
@Entity(name = "Car")
public class Car {
    //...
    @NotNull
    private Long mechanic_id;
```

From an Object perspective, this would be a unidirectional, one to one relationship with the Car requiring a `Mechanic.id` and the `Mechanic` not needing any back reference to `Car`.

All I want out of this is to store the `Mechanic.id` ONLY. For the purposes of this question it is not useful to have a `@OneToOne` (or `@OneToMany` etc) relationship with the entity reference, I'm explicitly trying to avoid that but still retain the underlying integrity that a FK will provide.

JPA 2 and I'm using EclipseLink.

Comment: What problems are you getting?  The foreign key is just a Long value like any other mapping.  You will need to manually set the value in your Car instead of setting it to a Mechanic instance though.  Are you trying to get DDL generation to create a constraint?

Comment: @Chris The point is to avoid the manual work and yes, the desire is for the FK to be created.